# Delicate data manipulation within a javascript object of single-value arrays

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, mean-stack, data-manipulation

I have a unique problem that I am trying to solve with some complex javascript code. For your information I am using MongoDB, NodeJS, ExpressJS, and VueJS as my technology stack.

I am writing an application that makes api calls to an outside partner of mine that is returning a huge xml based data file. (Unfortunately they are incapable of sending JSON data). After I receive the data from them, I run it through the parseString command of the xml2js library. But the way that it sends the code back is really really strange. From the outside it looks fine, it's an array of objects: [ {object1},{object2},....{objectN} ]. but when you look at the individual objects, it formats the data strangely:

---

```
    object1 = {
       key1: [ 'string' ],
       key2: [ '01234657' ],
       key3: [ 'email@email.com' ],
       key4: [{ 
             key5: [ '8372655573' ],
             key6: [ '25.00' ],
             key7: [ 'description of item purchased' ]
             }],
       key8: [ 'otherData' ],
// .......and so on until
       NthKey: [ 'dataType' ]    
    }
```

---

I anticipated that the majority of the data I was going to receive was going to consist of single key to single data value pairs, with a few exceptions. But for every single key of the returned object from parseString they assign the value to an array as a string, no matter what. And for the times that a key has a bunch of different data types entered into it (such as with key4 in the example above), I have to dig down into not only an array, but also a nested object inside that array, and into the individual keys that are associated with my data.....
I find that really strange and difficult to work with because now I have to create a bunch of loops that go through and create basically a carbon copy of object 1 except that it looks like this:

---

```
    object1CarbonCopy = {
        key1: String,
        key2: Number,
        key3: email,
        key4: {
            key5: Number,
            key6: Number,
            key7: String 
        },
        key8: String
// and so on until........
        NthKey: 'dataType'
    }
```

---

Do any of you have advice on code that could accomplish this? or if there are settings/options that I can pass into xml2js to change how it spits out the data? Any advice at all would be very appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried other XML-> json libraries?  It's clear enough why a library might make this choice.  How is it to know that this is an element which can only occur once and should be transformed into a scalar versus one which can occur multiple times and should become an array, when there happens to be only one present?  So it's doing the universal translation.  But perhaps another library, or this one with some hints, can make other choices in this circumstance.

Comment: Hey Scott, I have not, but I just found something in the xml2js docs that I am going to try.

Answer (score 0):

So I learned a valuable lesson today, sometimes you need to read through the docs multiple times because you miss things. It turns out that there is an option that turns off that automatic array inserting junk:

```
parser = new xml2js.Parser( {explicitArray: false} );
```

If you are viewing this question and don't know what the problem is, pass {explicitArray: false} as a parameter to your Parser constructor